# graphicImage não renderiza: ?pfdrid_c=true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou tentatndo exibir uma imagem com , mas não está sendo exibido em nenhum navegador.

Na minha página eu faço a chamada da imagem do modo:

```
<p:graphicImage value="/upload/#{desap.foto}" height="140"
                                width="140" />
```

e quando compilo e coloco em inspecionar elemento ele aparece da seguinte forma:

```
src="/ajudeaencontrar/upload/444?pfdrid_c=true"
```

**...Editando**

Esse é o modo como está o meu ManagedBean.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "desapBean")
@SessionScoped

public class CadastroDesaparecidoBean {

private Desaparecido desaparecido;
private DescricaoDesaparecido descricao;
private List<Desaparecido> listaDesaparecido;
private String situacao = null;

// Pega o usuário logado
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{uBean.usuario}")
private Usuario responsavel;

private UploadArquivo arquivo = new UploadArquivo();

private boolean skip;
private boolean isdeficiencia = false;
private boolean booEditar = false;

@PostConstruct
public void inicializar() {

    try {
        limpar();
        listaDesaparecido = new DesaparecidoJPA()
                .buscarDesaparecidosPorIdResponsavel2(responsavel);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Não foi possível resgatar os dados");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void limpar() {
    desaparecido = new Desaparecido();
    descricao = new DescricaoDesaparecido();
    arquivo = new UploadArquivo();
}
...

/*
 * Metodo para realizar o upload de uma foto Os tipos de dados sao validados
 * no Primefaces
 */
public void uploadAction(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        this.arquivo.fileUpload(event, ".jpg");
        this.desaparecido.setFoto(this.arquivo.getNome());

        fc.addMessage("formcaddesap", new FacesMessage("", event.getFile()
                .getFileName() + " foi carregada."));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        fc.addMessage("formcaddesap", new FacesMessage("", event.getFile()
                .getFileName() + " não foi carregada."));
    }
}

public String cadastrar() {

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {

...

        new DesaparecidoJPA().gravar(desaparecido);

        this.arquivo.gravar();

        FacesUtil.addSuccessMessage(desaparecido.getNome()
                + " cadastrado com sucesso.");

        System.out.println("arquivo gravado: " + arquivo.getNome());

        inicializar();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        FacesUtil.addSuccessMessage("Dados não foram armazenados!");
    }

    return "/admin/painelresp?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

}

Esse é a Classe para Upload do arquivo:

```
public class UploadArquivo {

private String caminho;
private byte[] arquivo;
private String nome;

public UploadArquivo() {
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public String getRealPath() {

    FacesContext aFacesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ServletContext context = (ServletContext) aFacesContext
            .getExternalContext().getContext();
    //Caminho dentro do projeto no servidor - onde ficarao salvas. 
    return context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/upload/");
}

public void fileUpload(FileUploadEvent event, String tipo) throws Exception {
    this.nome = new java.util.Date().getTime() + "_"
            + event.getFile().getSize() + tipo;

    this.arquivo = event.getFile().getContents();
    this.caminho = getRealPath() + getNome();

    File file = new File(getRealPath());
    file.mkdirs();

    System.out.println("caminho: " + caminho);
    System.out.println("Nome: " + getNome());
}

public void gravar() {

    try {

        FileOutputStream fos;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(this.caminho);
        fos.write(this.arquivo);
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
}
```

Esse é o trecho do Bean que carrega a lista para exibir no Datagrid:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "api")
@SessionScoped
public class AplicacaoBean {

private Desaparecido desaparecido;
private DescricaoDesaparecido descricao;
private List<Desaparecido> lista;
private List<Desaparecido> resultados = new ArrayList<Desaparecido>();
    @PostConstruct
public void inicializar() {
     try {
          desaparecido = new Desaparecido();
          lista = new DesaparecidoJPA().listar();
     } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
public List<Desaparecido> getLista() {
    return lista;
}
//Getters and Setters...
```

**O atributo foto do Entity Desaparecido é do tipo String.**

A foto está sendo gravada corretamente no servidor, eu coloquei para imprimir o caminho e ele mostra: 
`C:\workspace\Java EE SE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\ajudeaencontrar\WEB-INF\upload`

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como resolver isso? Estou querendo exibir a foto para o usuário. Já procurei aqui no site, mas não encontrei nada específico.

Comment: Amigo, poste o trecho do seu bean para que o entendimento seja facilitado.

Comment: Ok, editei e inclui o MB com Upload de arquivos.

Comment: No trecho `System.out.println("Nome: " + getNome());` o que é impresso?

Comment: Outra coisa, essa imagem que você está tentando visualizar, ela é chamada em uma outra view ou é ainda na mesma view do upload?

Comment: Ela exibe o nome que foi gerado pela minha regra no código, a  impressão fica assim: `Nome: 1447176144390_2247.jpg`.

Exemplo de impressão de Caminho: `C:\workspace\Java EE SE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ajudeaencontrar\WEB-INF\upload1447176144390_2247.jpg`.

No BD ele só grava o nome: `1447176144390_2247.jpg`.

Eu tento visualizar em outra view SessionScoped, onde o cliente pesquisa e deve ser exibida a foto juntamente com os outros dados.

Comment: Uma dúvida, nesse trecho: `src="/ajudeaencontrar/upload/444?pfdrid_c=true"` não deveria ser mostrado o `WEB-INF` também?

Comment: Na verdade eu já estava fazendo assim, informando o caminho a partir do WEB-INF, mas também não funcionou e fui pesquisar em um exemplo na web e lá era exibido a partir do diretório dentro do WEB-INF. Fiz alteração aqui em outra máquina para testar, mas tbm não roda: ficou assim: `src="/ajudeaencontrar/WEB-INF/upload/444.jpg?pfdrid_c=true"`

Comment: Coloca o `cache="false"` no teu graphicImage

Comment: Ainda não aparece a imagem, mas no html agora está assim: `src="/ajudeaencontrar/WEB-INF/upload/444.jpg?pfdrid_c=false&uid=6ffa29b6-a26d-4fc8-9502-2a981a69979b"`

Comment: Existe esse arquivo 444.jpg?

Comment: Pq seu bean tem o name desapBean e você chama somente desap.foto no xhtml?

Comment: É porque eu estou exibindo dentro de um outro view que referencia o Bean api `<p:dataGrid var="desap" value="#{api.lista}" ...>`. Sim, os arquivos existem e estão no caminho informado na impressão.

No meu bean "api" eu carrego uma lista de um Entity com um campo String da foto. No p:graphicImage estou informando o caminho + o nome da foto de um objeto.

Comment: coloquei um trecho com o Bean "api".

Comment: Consegui resolver, valeu pela ajuda @WeslleyTavares, mas verifiquei um exemplo onde o método getRealPath() da minha classe UploadArquivo só retorna desse jeito `return context.getRealPath("/");` e não o caminho completo como eu fazia.
Outra coisa que tive que alterar foi o caminho, tive que tirar do diretorio META-INF porque não estava funcionando, talvez seja pq estou usando Maven; coloquei dessa forma: `this.caminho = getRealPath() + "/upload/" + getNome();` e na chamada eu coloquei assim: `<h:graphicImage value="./upload/#{desap.foto}">`, onde "desap" é minha variável do p:dataGrid.